# JS: Problem with function returning function with evaluated variables

Tags: javascript, function, serialization

I want to create a higher-level function that returns functions in order to be serialized and sent to another machine.

For example I want to create a function that returns `Hello world`, by passing `world` to a generator function and afterwards serialize by toString:

```js
function returnAnotherFunction(name) {
  return () => { return `Hello ${name}`}
}

const helloWorldFunction = returnAnotherFunction('world')

const serializedFunction = helloWorldFunction.toString()
console.log(serializedFunction)
// prints: () => { return `Hello ${name}`}
// I want: () => { return `Hello world`}
```

Instead, the returned serialized function does still rely on the variable. I need to serialize the function, so I need it without the variable. I am having problems finding the right keywords for a search and am happy with any help!

Comment: Hmm, serializing functions to strings is a pretty unusual thing to do in JS. Is there another way to achieve your goal?

Comment: I know that it is unusual, but I have to work with the existing project structure. Where a config object is created on the server and loaded + evaluated by the client. The config does already include functions.
I thought it would be straight foward to improve the thing already by using the "generator function".

Comment: can you elaborate why you need to serialized function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to have a string containing a function definition with variables evaluated, that string template literal needs to be evaluated before being part of the function definition of which you need to output the body.

If you print the function definition as you did in your example, the template literal won't be evaluated and will print out as is.

The only way I know of creating a function definition dynamically so that it contains in the body a string that was already evaluted is using `eval()` despite it being a strategy ***NOT RECOMMENDED***

Unfortunately I don't know any better method than this to achieve your goal so I will share it for the sake of excercise.

This is a demo:

```js
function returnAnotherFunction(name) {  
  return eval(`(function(){return 'Hello ${name}';})`);  
}

const helloWorldFunction = returnAnotherFunction('world');

const serializedFunction = helloWorldFunction.toString();
console.log(`function body: "${serializedFunction}"`);
console.log(`function returns: "${helloWorldFunction()}"`);
```

Comment: Thanks. This does actually work. But I of course know the risks of eval()

Comment: and please let me be more explicit.. I know that strategy doesn't scale that well if your function body goes beyond a mere returning a template literal. I just followed literally your question and did my best to fulfill the request without questioning deeper. There's still the chance that your problem might be better addressed knowing more in details how to better factor your logic.